# Allow Docker Container with MacVLAN network to access Wireguard connected remote

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker, wireguard

I do have two servers:

- **Server A**: a local NAS running RHEL 8.5 (5.17.1 kernel - so it has native wireguard support); local IP `192.168.1.1`
- **Server B**: a VPS with debian 11.3 (5.10.0 kernel - also has wireguard support)

Now my local network has a FritzBox with IP: `192.168.0.1`. It's DHCP is configured with a network mask of `22`.

I splitted my network into:

- 192.168.0.x for `normal devices`
- 192.168.1.x for servers with static IPs
- 192.168.2.x for Docker Containers run on **Server A** (later  more on that one)

I used to run `fastd` on **Server A & B** (Server B *was* IP `192.168.1.2`) and had a bridge device on **Server A** that managed `local ethernet`, `docker macvlan` and the `tap device from fastd`. That way `normal devices` as well as docker container where able to reach **Server B**.

Because of package loss (>6%) of my local internet lately, `fastd` stopped working (package loss of over 89%) and I tried replacing `fastd` with `wireguard`.
But wireguard only works on Layer 3. That broke my routing via the bridge that I used with fastd.

The think is, I'm able to get all connections to work (e.g. `192.168.0.10` can reach `10.0.0.1`; **Server B** can reach `192.168.0.x`, `192.168.1.x` and `192.168.2.x`), except the Docker Containers on **Server A**. They CAN NOT reach **Server B**.

I would imagine that there is something wrong with my `iptables` or the `macvlan device` itself.

**I'm also open for suggestions how to rebuild the network from scratch**

One last thing, docker container that only have the default network are able to reach **Server B**.

---

### Device Details:

#### Docker Container:

```
# how I created the macvlan

$ docker network create -d macvlan --subnet 192.168.2.0/22 --gateway 192.168.0.1 --ip-range 192.168.2.2/24  --aux-address 'host=192.168.2.1' --aux-address 'block=192.168.2.0' -o parent=mesh-bridge macvlan-docker

# and I have a script that runs on boot:

#!/bin/bash

ip link add docker-shim link mesh-bridge type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev docker-shim
ip link set docker-shim up


$ docker inspect
...
"Networks": {
                "macvlan-docker": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "192.168.2.5"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "4c5782507c3f",
                        "munin"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "c6ef34cba56ebef8de2107e085473098637c51e14354cf6840c29b26947b1798",
                    "EndpointID": "be818e3e67e8d028aebfe41ef7f648418665efe7dbe3488ea108a744da649c79",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.2.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 22,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:02:05",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
...

# from within the container

root@4c5782507c3f:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
89: eth0@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:02:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.2.5/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@4c5782507c3f:/# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.5 
root@4c5782507c3f:/# ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 1.1.168.192)
```

#### Server A:

```
# I stripped devices that are unreleated
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master mesh-bridge state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:20:65:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: mesh-bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:20:65:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/23 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute mesh-bridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8a7b:703c:eb38:12c0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:19:fd:18:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
28: docker-shim@mesh-bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:a2:68:5c:38:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.1/24 scope global docker-shim
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4a2:68ff:fe5c:3809/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
132: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.2/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

-----

$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev mesh-bridge proto static metric 425 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 scope link 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/23 dev mesh-bridge proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 425 
192.168.2.0/24 dev docker-shim proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1 

-----

# wireguard config

[Interface]
PrivateKey = <<key>>
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE; 


[Peer]
PublicKey = <<key>>
Endpoint = <<public ip of server b>>:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
```

#### Server B:

```
$ ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:18:69:37:a7:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s3
    inet <public ip>/22 brd <netmask> scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 2597782sec preferred_lft 2597782sec
    inet6 <public ipv6>::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 <other ipv6>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:91:ad:db:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
37: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.1/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

-----

$ ip route
default via <gateway> dev ens3 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 scope link 
<vps network>/22 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src <public ip> 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/22 dev wg0 scope link 

-----

# wireguard config

[Interface]
PrivateKey = <<key>>
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE;

[Peer]
PublicKey = <<key>>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24, 192.168.0.0/22
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

#### FritzBox

The `FritzBox` has a static route for `10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1`. This way other devices on the network can reach **Server B**

Comment: The prefix lengths in your configuration is quite messed up. It seems that you want all three types of hosts in one single broadcast domain, yet you aren't using the prefix length `/22` consistently. (While normally there's no point in doing so, technically you could use multiple IP subnets, e.g. three `/24`, in a single BD, but that is not the same thing as mixing conflicting `/22` ~ `/24` like you are doing now.)

Comment: Besides, what's the point in using (bridge mode) MACVLANs that are attached to a bridge?

Comment: If the macvlan is not part of the bridge, another device on the local network, like 192.168.0.10 was not able to see devices on the 192.168.2.x subnet. The reason for using /23 on the bridge is that otherwise **Server A** would send packages twice to the .2.x subnet.

Comment: For clarification, I run containers on **Server A"" that provide their own Webserver/ -service like pihole, Munn, minio. That's why I want to be able to reach them from everywhere and run multiple containers that might bind to the same port.

Comment: @TomYan - see https://collabnix.com/2-minutes-to-docker-macvlan-networking-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: There's no problem in putting all the hosts / containers in a single BD. It's merely that I don't see much point in using MACVLANs when you are attaching them to a bridge. (Why not just make the containers use the bridge with taps?) I have no idea what you mean by "sent twice", but indeed you probably shouldn't have IP configured on both the bridge and the host-side MACVLAN. Rather you should only configure one on either of them if you insist on such set-up, and again all the hosts in the BD should have `/22` as prefix/mask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135458/discussion-between-lexxxel-and-tom-yan).